# webpack build to multiple files

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

I have web pack application and want to build output multiple files not a single javascript file. for example if I have such folder structure

```
components
 1.js
 2.js
actions
 1.js.
 2.js
```

my webpack build have to compile files in same folder structure. How i can achieve that?

I tried babel cli:

```
babel ./src --out-dir ./lib --source-maps --presets es2015,react --plugins babel-plugin-add-module-exports,babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy,babel-plugin-transform-class-properties --watch
```

It outputs files as I wanted but getting error

> Cannot resolve module

Because it does not know anything about webpack resolve.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please read tag descriptions! [tag:babel] is not the right tag (and it explicitly says that too): *"Python internationalization library with an emphasis on web-based applications. For questions about the JavaScript library, please use [babeljs]."*

Answer (score 2):

Getting webpack to output multiple files is possible but it does have limitations.  First it's important to understand how this works.  Webpack actually provides a runtime script that can load code "chunks" as they are needed, this is important for large applications so the user doesn't have to download the javascript for the entire app just to see the homepage.  But webpack needs to keep track of these chunks and what they're named at build time to be able to load them correctly at run time.  For that reason it has it's own file naming conventions to enable this functionality. See more here: https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/. So you can require.ensure all of your deps, but they won't be named and foldered they way you describe as webpack's runtime wouldn't be able to find them in that case.

The other thing that's important to consider is that webpack is a bundler, so it's meant to bundle files.  Essentially your saying you don't want to bundle your files.  So if that's the case, you should probably look into using require.js.  Many people have moved from require to bundlers such as Wepback and Browserify as typically it's not efficient to download every little module seperately. But, every app is different so you may in fact have a good reason to not bundle.

If you do in fact want to do some bundling but want to optimize how it's done, then I can help with that as well, and webpack is certainly a great tool for that.  But I'll need to understand your use case a little more to give the best advice.

Comment: Thank you Ben for reply, I'm just trying to to achieve import { Login } from 'my-module/components'. I'm writing module with webpack which I will include in my webpack web application, just want to have such import, now I have import { components } from 'my-module' and can access Login like this  components.Login. Any advice?

Comment: It sounds like your having a little trouble with es6 import syntax actually and webpack will serve your needs just fine.  Can you send the folder structure you want to have for my-module/components? The syntax it sounds like you're trying to requires a file called components.js(x) in the my-module folder with an export that looks like this: `export class Login...`.  It seems like what you may actually want to do is have a separate file in a components folder for login, called Login.jsx.  In that case Login.jsx shoud have `export default Login;` at the bottom (assuming Login is a Component).

Comment: If Login.jsx is it's own file and does `export default`, then you need to import ti like this: `import Login from 'my-modules/components/Login';`

Comment: If you're really attached to `import { Login } from 'my-modules/components';` then you could put an index.js file in the components folder that both imported and exported Login.jsx, it could do this for example: `import Login from './Login';`  then `export Login`. I think that'd work, but it is not conventional and requires unnecessary boilerplate every time you add a component.